At 2D Ising model, M goes to 0 When T=0.5
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def Make_Lattice(L):

    Lattice = np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=(L, L))

    return Lattice



def Energy_Change(Lattice, x, y, J, L):

    spin = Lattice[x, y]

    nearby = Lattice[(x - 1) % L, y] + Lattice[(x + 1) % L, y] + Lattice[x, (y - 1) % L] + Lattice[x, (y + 1) % L]

    Delta_E = 2 * J * spin * nearby

    return Delta_E



def Metropolis_step(Lattice, T, L, J):

    x = np.random.randint(0, L)

    y = np.random.randint(0, L)

    delta_E = Energy_Change(Lattice, x, y, J, L)



    prob = np.exp(-delta_E / T)

    

    if delta_E < 0 or np.random.random() < prob:

        Lattice[x, y] *= -1



def Metropolis(L, T, J, steps):

    Lattice = Make_Lattice(L)



    stp = []

    density = []



    for step in range(steps):

        Metropolis_step(Lattice, T, L, J)



        if step % 50 == 0:

            stp.append(step)

            density.append(np.abs(np.sum(Lattice)) / (L * L))



    return stp, density



#-------------------------------------------



L = 12

T = 0.5

J = 1

steps = 5000



#-------------------------------------------



stp, density = Metropolis(L, T, J, steps)



plt.plot(stp, density, "-", color="b")

plt.xlabel("Step")

plt.ylabel("Lattice Density")

plt.title("Step - Lattice Density")

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()

This is my code, and I'm having problem because when I run this code, sometimes Lattice Density(or Magnetization) goes to 0.
My question is Is there any problems in my code?
I've tried to make steps to 100,000times but it didn't worked.
Also I've tried to make Lattice bigger, but it didn't worked
